# Targeting only 1 event in DOM

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom

In the picture below, I want to open a modal when a user clicks anywhere within in the yellow block, including if they click on the white ‘+’ sign. The problem is, the click event happens on a different target depending on whether the user clicks on the yellow portion, or on the white ‘+’ sign.

In my JavaScript code, I have been handing it like this so far, but I wonder if there is a better, shorter way of doing this that doesn’t require the II operator:

```
function openModal(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('project-box__picture-box') || e.target.classList.contains('project-box__icon')) {
    modalEl.classList.add('open');
  }
}
```

[image: DOM Events]

Comment: Welcome to code review! When posting code for review it helps to Add a relevant language tag (similar to your DOM tag)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! So that we can give you proper advice, please include your HTML as well. (Press Ctrl-M in the question editor to make a live demo.)

Answer (score 1):

I can give you two ways to approach this: via JavaScript or CSS.

## JavaScript

You can use the `.closest()` method of the `HTMLElement` interface. You need to pass it a CSS selector, and it will find you the closest DOM ancestor of the element that matches the given selector, or `null` if no such ancestor was found.

In this case, you could use it like this:

```
function openModal(e) {
  if (e.target.closest('.project-box__picture-box')) {
    modalEl.classList.add('open');
  }
}
```

[(full method reference here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

## CSS

The other option is to use the `pointer-events` CSS property. If you set this to `none` on all elements inside the clickable box, then those elements will not be allowed to be the targets of mouse events; instead, the target will be the closest ancestor that has pointer events enabled.

In this case, you'd need to add this CSS:

```
.project-box__picture-box * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

And this JS:

```
function openModal(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('project-box__picture-box')) {
    modalEl.classList.add('open');
  }
}
```

[(full property reference here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)